# sjPlot plot_model not displaying interaction names

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels, sjplot

I am running a generalised linear model with a lot of factors and their interactions.

```
modelFINAL<-  glmer(treatment ~ (1|Household_ID)+(1|Case)+(1|Villages)+
                      ProductionSystem*disease+
                      ProductionSystem*costs+  
                      ProductionSystem*education+ 
                      ProductionSystem*age+
                      costs*income+
                      age+
                      income,
                 data = GLM_data, family = binomial(link='logit'), 
                 control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)))
```

I want to visualise the model estimations with a forest plot. However, for some reason plot_model won't show the interaction terms on the y axis, it just says "conditional" for all of them (see picture).
[image]

This is my code:

```
plot_model(modelFINAL, show.values = TRUE,type='est',sort.est = T,transform=NULL,
 vline.color = "black",title="TITLE")`
```

I get the same result when I add `auto.labels=T` in plot_model.

tab_model seems to work fine, however it is inconsistently using and X or a : for interaction terms (see picture). Not sure if that is problematic or not.
[image]

This problem came up after I updated all my packages and to the new R and R studio versions, so it might be a bug? Or maybe something is wrong with my data?
Does someone know what I can do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reached out to the developer. If you update the siPlot and the parameter package it should work now.